# LWC component not available while adding in homepage

Tags: lightning-web-components

html :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Fetch Data from Apex - Wire a property">
        <template if:true={accounts.data}>
            <template for:each={accounts.data} for:item="acc">
                <p key={acc.id}>{acc.Name} ---> {acc.phone}</p>

            </template>

        </template>
        <template if:true={accounts.error}>
            {accounts.error}

        </template>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

### JS file :

```
import { LightningElement , wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/getAccountData.getAccountList';

export default class Acclwcapex extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getAccountList) accounts;
}
```

### XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
      <targets>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>

    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>

    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>

  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

### Apex clas:

```
public with sharing class getAccountData {
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<Account> getAccountList(){
       list<Account> VarAcclist = New list<Account>();
       VarAcclist = [SELECT Id,Name,Industry,Website,Phone from Account];
       return VarAcclist;
     
   }
}
```

Comment: isexposed = true and targets are also added

Comment: You can use `Ctrl-K` or `{}` in the editor bar to format code correctly. I've taken care of it for you this time. Since you're new here, you may also want to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. I hope you enjoy your stay here!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that to your lightning record page as well. Without adding that to your lightning record page that won't be appeared. For that you have to follow the steps given below.

1. Open the home page in your org.
2. Go to 'Set up' and click on 'Edit Page'.

[image]

3. Then you will navigate to a page like below. From the most left tab, you can scroll down till 'Custom' components. There you can see your LWC component as I have highlighted below.

[image]

4. You can just click on your component and drag and drop it wherever you need.
5. Then save the page
6. Once you refreshing the browser , please make sure to open inspect(Ctrl+Shift+I) and right click on the refresh icon on the browser and click on 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'. Hopefully your component will get appear on your home page